# Riemann Integration Help

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

May I know if my proof to this problem is correct? Thank you.

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&0 &&,x=0 \vee x\in [0,1]-\mathbb{Q}\\
&\frac{1}{q} &&,x=\frac{p}{q} \wedge p,q\in\mathbb{N} \wedge gcd(p,q)=1 \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Is $f$ integrable on $[0,1] ?$

Proof:
Given $\epsilon >0,$ let $B= \left\{{\frac{p}{q}\in[0,1]: gcd(p,q)=1, f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{1}{q}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}}\right\}$. Then B is finite. Consider partition $P=\left\{x_{0}=0,x_{2},...,x_{n}=1\right\}$of $[0,1]$ such that sum of length of subintervals, $[x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$ containing elements of B $< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. It follows that $f(x) \leq\frac{\epsilon}{2},\forall x\in [x_{i-1},x_{i-1}]$ where $B \cap[x_{i-1},x_{i}] =\varnothing$.

Then, $U(f,P)$ $=\sum_{B \cap[x_{i-1},x_{i}] \neq\varnothing} sup\left\{f(x): x\in [x_{i-1},x_{i}]\right\}\triangle x_{i}+\sum_{B \cap[x_{i-1},x_{i}] =\varnothing} sup\left\{f(x): x\in [x_{i-1},x_{i}]\right\}\triangle x_{i} $  $\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

Also, $L(f,P)=0$ for any partition $P$

Hence, $\int_{a}^{b} f  =0  $

Comment: Looks perfect to me. This is closely related to the proof that a function which is continuous outside of a set of zero (Lebesgue-)measure is Riemann-integrable (the converse being the more involved part of this well-known equivalency).